# App Request Dialog has sides cut off when app is displayed in a Facebook page tab - how to make fit?

Tags: dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk

Seems that the area is only about 470 px wide for some reason? Not even 520. Maybe I can shrink the App request dialog somehow, but not seeing a param to constrain it. It seems to want to be about 570 pixels wide. Plenty of room if they just go straight to the App of course. Right now I'm doing it as a popup as a work around.

Answer (score 0):

The facebook app "window" is 520px by 800px. Make sure you set padding and margin to 0 on your body element to take advantage of the full size.

I would try repositioning your app request dialog to make it fit within the allowed size.

Comment: Yes, I'll have to look at my app's padding and margin - would you know how to reposition the dialog that this call makes:         FB.ui(
     { method: 'apprequests',
       message: 'I just got a great Quote',
       title: 'Please Recommend my company to your Friends!'
     },
     function(response){
       if (response) {
         alert('Thank you for recommending my company to your friends!');
       }
     });

Comment: Depends on what triggers the call.  If it's an anchor element, repositioning the anchor should reposition the dialog that opens.